# Disabling resize window below 250px

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello i was preparing a website and came accross that on rezing the window below 250px it looses its responsivity especially on firefox. Is there a way, i can disable rezing below  250px;

What i expect is javascript that will alert on rezing below 250px.
what i tried is

```
$(function () {

    $(window).bind("resize", function () {
        console.log($(this).width())
        if ($(this).width() < 250) {
           alert('resizing below 250px may cause in losing of responsivity');
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: What is going wrong with what you tried?

Comment: if your website is good on 320px than you are good to go and below 320 don't worry about it. minimum screen size we make 320 px.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically it´s possible to Resize the browser window programmatically.
But it´s barely supperted by browsers, so i wont recommend it.

What you can do is give the body a minimum width. If you do that, the body will be scrollable if the browser window reaches the given width.

```
body{
  min-width:250px;
  overflow-x:scroll
}
```

But i dont realy see a reason to do this.